# Can't return user total presence.status of Global

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want to retrieve all my users of all guilds where my bot is used at.
What i need is a total(global) of these :

```
presence?.status == "offline")
presence?.status == "online")
presence?.status == "DND")
presence?.status == "bots")
```

well what i did is this and it returned 0 :

```
let userCount = message.client.users.cache.filter(member => member.presence?.status == "offline").size
    console.log("total",userCount)
```

If i want to return everyone as a total(global) that works normal:

```
let userCount = message.client.users.cache.size;
console.log("total",userCount)
```

if i do this i get them but seperate,i need a total.

```
client.guilds.cache.forEach((guild) => {

const total = guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.presence?.status == "online").size
console.log(total)
}
```

any idea how to do this? i'm on v13

regards

Comment: You could try to use how v12 used `User.presence`, it tried to find a guild with the member in it, and get the presence there

Comment: Hi @MrMythical  well the last code does retrieve it, but its seperate, i want a total of all the guilds together, not status of each guild seperate..

Comment: @Hector If my answer worked, make sure to mark it as the best answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `forEach()` might be a possible solution. We are going to use the increment operator (`++`). For example, something like this should work:

```js
let userCount = 0;
client.guilds.cache.forEach((guild) => {
    Array.from(guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.presence?.status === 'online').values()).forEach(() => userCount++);
});

console.log(userCount);
```

**Hoped this helped!**