# Discordjs how to count in ForEach loop and get a total value?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have this code, it counts all the online people of all guilds,
it shows up like this for example 5 guilds:

12
13
14
15
16

i use this code, but i want it to return as 1 total and not 5 seperate value's.
Regards

```
client.guilds.cache.forEach((guild) => {
         const total = guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.presence?.status == "online").size
         console.log("per 1", total)
        
         
        
         
         
           const guilds = [
    { memberCount: total }
];

const totalMembers = guilds
  .map((guild) => guild.memberCount)
  .reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr, 0);

console.log("alles",totalMembers);
         
         })
```

Comment: does ur guilds look like `[{ memberCount: 12 },{ memberCount: 13 },{ memberCount: 14 },{ memberCount: 15 },{ memberCount: 16 }
]`

Comment: you can have a variable outside forEach `let totalMembers = 0` and inside foreach add total to totalMembers. then outside the foreach console log and you can get the whole total

Comment: well when i use console.log("alles",totalMembers); it returns like this under eachother 
 alles 22   alles 10  alles 39  alles 40 alles 2.   i dont know how to do this , would be great if anyone can show me how.  regards and thanks for the reactions

Comment: try `let totalMembers = 0; client.guilds.cache.forEach((guild) => {
         const total = guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.presence?.status == "online").size; totalMembers+=total}) console.log("alles",totalMembers);`

Comment: @cmgchess
u made my day, it worked thanks !!!!

Comment: @Hector Why did you post two different questions that include the same thing?

Comment: I used @cmgchess comment and made it into an answer. If it helped, please mark it as the best answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@cmdchess](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13583510/cmgchess) said, you can use this solution using the addition assignment operator (`+=`). For example, this should work:

```js
let totalMembers = 0;
client.guilds.cache.forEach((guild) => {
    const total = guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.presence?.status === 'online').size;
    totalMembers += total;
});

console.log('alles', totalMembers);
```

You can also achieve this using the increment operator (`++`). See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71146093/cant-return-user-total-presence-status-of-global/71216342#71216342) for that solution. This should also work using that:

```js
let userCount = 0;
client.guilds.cache.forEach((guild) => {
    Array.from(guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.presence?.status === 'online').values()).forEach(() => userCount++);
});

console.log(userCount);
```

**Hoped this helped!**